# Why the alex-shpak/hugo-book does not work in RStudio?

Tags: themes, rstudio, hugo

I followed this workflow to install the theme in a new RStudio project. Then, I got the following error. Now, the site is created, but it has a bad format.

Workflow used: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html

[image]

Error:

> blogdown::new_site(theme = 'alex-shpak/hugo-book')
>   trying URL 'https://github.com/alex-shpak/hugo-book/archive/master.zip'
>   downloaded 933 KB
>
> ERROR 2020/02/19 15:26:45 Failed to read Git log: fatal: not a git
>   repository (or any of the parent directories): .git Error: logged 1
>   error(s)
>
> Warning: You are recommended to ignore certain files in config.toml:
>   set the option ignoreFiles = ["\.Rmd$", "\.Rmarkdown$", "_files$",
>   "_cache$"] Rendering content/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd Building
>   sites … ERROR 2020/02/19 15:26:48 Failed to read Git log: fatal: not a
>   git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git WARN
>   2020/02/19 15:26:48 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "page":
>   You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup
>   Rules for this combination. WARN 2020/02/19 15:26:48 found no layout
>   file for "HTML" for kind "section": You should create a template file
>   which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination. Total in
>   259 ms Error: Error building site: logged 1 error(s) To stop the
>   server, run servr::daemon_stop(1) or restart your R session Serving
>   the directory /Users/ovandef/Dropbox/rprojects/personal at
>   http://127.0.0.1:4321/'https://example.com/'